# Multiple Themes with their own url.py and views.py in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to build a web-application in Django similar to WordPress. Where each theme folder will have it's own set of url.py, view.py, stylesheet etc.

So far, I have been able to implement multiple themes, but all of theme rely on a single common url.py & views.py. Which gives less flexibility. Themes are placed inside a "Templates" folder on root.[image]

I want each theme to process and display data independently just like WordPress theme that has their own PHP scripts.

Any help in achieving this will be highly appreciated.